# Define a digital analytics structure

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

We are going to launch a new site with this structure: **domain.com** for the global site and **domain.cl**, **.ve**, **.eu** for different countries/regions. We are building the analytics tag strategy first.

In addition, we provide the service of buying tickets in sub-domains. For example **tickets.CLIENT.com**

We are planning to create a GTM container for the real site and another for development issues. Each one with GA properties separately. Then configure cross-domain tracking.

Our question now is: Should We create a property for each client that contracts our ticket service?.
Or do we use the property by country and use reports with filters?.

As there will be electronic commerce of the tickets we want to make the best possible decision.

Thanks in an advance,

Angel

Answer (score 0):

If you create a property for each domain you will not be able to perform the cross-domain (unless you have Analytics 360).

So you could have a unique property where you send all data and also many separate properties to make analysis easier on the single site avoiding sampling problem.